# Add Image with Strip Tags or Into Form to Email Response

Tags: php, html, forms, strip-tags

I really don't know much about Strip Tags so this may not even be possible.

I have a survey that users fill out online. Part of this survey has a question where they are required to vote on a star rating. At the moment, once completed, it emails through with that star rating number (i.e. 1 - 5). What I would like, is to insert an image instead of the numbers, so that I can visually show the star rating selection. I'm just not sure where to insert that image with the Strip Tag?

Or perhaps it should be going in where "value" is on the frontend? Afterall, this is what's being called in the email.

Any insight is appreciated!

Front-end HTML side:

```
<div class="question-sub"><p>Ease of making your reservation</p>        </div>

<span class="rating">

         <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
            id="rating-input-1-1" name="res-ease5" value="5">
        <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
            id="rating-input-1-2" name="res-ease4" value="4">
        <label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>        
       <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
            id="rating-input-1-3" name="res-ease3" value="3">
        <label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>        
         <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
            id="rating-input-1-4" name="res-ease2" value="2">
        <label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>       
                <input type="radio" class="rating-input"
            id="rating-input-1-5" name="res-ease1" value="1">
        <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
    </span>
```

Backend PHP side:

```
$message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Ease of making your reservation: </td><td width='50%'>" . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease5']) . "" . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease4']) . "" . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease3']) . "" . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease2']) . "" . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease1']) . "</td></tr>";
```

UPDATE:

Dagon's answer below works perfectly but it is showing the URL rather than embedding the image into the actual email. Here is the code I am using:

```
$img="http://myurl.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res'].'.jpg';
```

Comment: im confused as to what you think `strip_tags()` has to do with adding an image to an email

Comment: Because this is what is calling the item on the frontend to post in the email. I.e. . strip_tags($_POST['res-ease5'])

Comment: i dont think you know what the function does. if you want to put an image in the email just add the html for it,

Comment: Right, but where am I putting that? Into the 'value' field?

Comment: what 'value' field? just add the html in $message

Comment: The image only shows based on their response. So it has to somehow correlate back to the form and what rating they choose.

Comment: You're not following the question properly.

Comment: so pick the image based on their selection, its still just add the html to `$message` - oh im not following, my bad - i'll go back to work then

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean. If I add an image to the $message field it is going to appear for every response they give. I need a different image depending on their selection.

Comment: that's were the ' pick the image based on their selection' comes in

Comment: Right, but how do I do THAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a start the radio buttons are wrong, each should have the *same* name attribute:

so assume you changed then all to **res**

so in the post array you have `$_POST['res']` being 1-5

name the images you want to use **star[1-5].jpg**

create the img variable for use in the message:

```
$img="<img src='YOUR WEBSITE URL/star".$_POST['res'].".jpg'>";
```

then change $message to:

```
$message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Ease of making your reservation: </td><td width='50%'>$img</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. In the email itself though it is showing the link rather than an image. Can't quite see why but will update my code above now. Just to confirm if I visit the link it shows the image. It's just not embedding it into the email itself.

Comment: I have marked this as correct because it works, but one thing I didn't mention (and therefore you presumed) is that I have multiple questions. So now, with this code, it gives the same image (and therefore the same response) for every question. How do I link it to the specific question like the strip_tag was doing?

Comment: ^ I solved the above by using $img2 etc for future questions. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it but it seems to be working.

Comment: strip_tags is a function to remove tags from a string, i don't know why you keep mentioning it, its not an issue here at all